# My PowerUp wont work if I place more than one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey I made a powerup script for my game. It is intended to boost the player, and it does, but when I place more than one powerup that the player can collide with it doesnt work. I even rewrote the whole script so I didnt use static variable cause I thought that was the problem, but apparently not. It works perfectly when I have one powerup in the map but when I place two or more it does not work but still prints my debug.log to console.

Code:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool boosting = false;
    public GameObject effect;
    public AudioSource clip;


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            if (!boosting)
            {
                //Audio play
                clip.Play();
                //Start effect at powerups position
                GameObject explosion = Instantiate(effect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                Destroy(explosion, 2);

                //disable collider and meshrender
                GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
                GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;

                //Get the tankmovementscript via the collider and increase the speed
                TankMovement collidedMovement = other.gameObject.GetComponent<TankMovement>();
                collidedMovement.m_Speed = 20f;

                boosting = true;
                Debug.Log(boosting);
                StartCoroutine(coolDown());
            }
        }
        else if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player1"))
        {
            if(!boosting)
            {
            //Audio play
            clip.Play();

            //Start effect at powerups position
            GameObject explosion =Instantiate(effect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            Destroy(explosion, 2);

            //disable collider and meshrender
            GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;

            //Get the tankmovementscript via the collider and increase the speed
            TankMovement1 collidedMovement = other.gameObject.GetComponent<TankMovement1>();
            collidedMovement.m_Speed1 = 20f;

            boosting = true;
            Debug.Log(boosting);
            StartCoroutine(coolDown());
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator coolDown()
    {
        if (boosting == true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
            {
                boosting = false;

                //wait 4 seconds enable the powerup again
                GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
                GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = true;
                Debug.Log(boosting);


            }
        }
    }

     void reset()
     {
        //again find both tanks with name and get their movement script variable and change it back to normal
        GameObject.Find("Tank(Clone)").GetComponent<TankMovement>().m_Speed = 12f;
        GameObject.Find("Tank1(Clone)").GetComponent<TankMovement1>().m_Speed1 = 12f;

    }

    private void Update()
    {  //checking to see if the player is not boosting set speed to normal
        if (!boosting)
        {
            reset();
        }

    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you mentioned is simply because of your "Reset" function when you have more than two powerups, the others turn off the boosting and set the player speed to zero.

there are different approaches to this issue, one is declaring "boosting" field to static so that it'll be a shared property among all powerups, but it will have its side effects such as effects won't stack as intended;

so you have to implement a simple Effect system for the player to stack powerups effects and the responsibility of Powerups would be only delivering these effects, NOT activating/ deactivating them.

a simple implementation could be like:

effects:

```
public interface IEffect
{
    float Duration { get; set; }
    void Do(Player p);
    void Undo(Player p);
}

public class ActiveEffect
{
    public IEffect Effect { get; private set; }
    public float LeftTime;
    public ActiveEffect(IEffect effect)
    {
        Effect = effect;
        LeftTime = effect.Duration;
    }
}

public class SpeedBoost : IEffect
{
    public float Duration { get; set; }

    public SpeedBoost()
    {
        Duration = 4;
    }
    public void Do(Player p)
    {
        p.speed = 40f;
    }

    public void Undo(Player p)
    {
        p.speed = 20f;
    }
}
```

your effectmanager:

```
public class EffectManager
{
    Dictionary<Type, ActiveEffect> _activeEffects = new Dictionary<Type, ActiveEffect>();
    public void AddEffect(IEffect effect)
    {
        var type = effect.GetType();
        if (_activeEffects.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            //reseting effect duration to max
            _activeEffects[type].LeftTime = effect.Duration;
        }
        else
        {
            var activeEffect = new ActiveEffect(effect);
            _activeEffects.Add(type, activeEffect);
            StartCoroutine(activeEffect);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Apply(ActiveEffect effect)
    {
        effect.Effect.Do(player);
        while (effect.LeftTime > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            effect.LeftTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        effect.Effect.Undo(player);
        _activeEffects.Remove(effect.Effect.GetType());
    }
}
```